# How do You Make Items Stay Centered on a Screen no Matter the Size?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make these boxes horizontally centered on the screen no matter what the area of the viewport is, but I just can't seem to do it. If anyone could help with this, I would appreciate it.

```html
        <div class = 'jobFields'>
            <div class = 'field-1'></div>
            <div class = 'field-2'></div>
            <div class = 'field-3'></div>
            <div class = 'field-4'></div>
            <div class = 'field-5'></div>
            <div class = 'field-6'></div>
            <div class = 'field-7'></div>
            <div class = 'field-8'></div>
            <style>
                .field-1 {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 250px;
                    height: 150px;
                    top: 400px;
                    left: 5%;
                    box-shadow: 10px 10px;
                    background-color: #0f0f0f;
                    color: #5e00bc;
                    z-index: 2;
                }

                .field-2 {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 250px;
                    height: 150px;
                    top: 400px;
                    left: 28.6%;
                    box-shadow: 10px 10px;
                    background-color: #0f0f0f;
                    color: #5e00bc;
                    z-index: 2;
                }

                .field-3 {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 250px;
                    height: 150px;
                    top: 400px;
                    left: 52.2%;
                    box-shadow: 10px 10px;
                    background-color: #0f0f0f;
                    color: #5e00bc;
                    z-index: 2;
                }

                .field-4 {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 250px;
                    height: 150px;
                    top: 400px;
                    left: 75.8%;
                    box-shadow: 10px 10px;
                    background-color: #0f0f0f;
                    color: #5e00bc;
                    z-index: 2;
                }

                .field-5 {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 250px;
                    height: 150px;
                    top: 620px;
                    left: 5%;
                    box-shadow: 10px 10px;
                    background-color: #0f0f0f;
                    color: #5e00bc;
                    z-index: 2;
                }

                .field-6 {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 250px;
                    height: 150px;
                    top: 620px;
                    left: 28.6%;
                    box-shadow: 10px 10px;
                    background-color: #0f0f0f;
                    color: #5e00bc;
                    z-index: 2;
                }

                .field-7 {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 250px;
                    height: 150px;
                    top: 620px;
                    left: 52.2%;
                    box-shadow: 10px 10px;
                    background-color: #0f0f0f;
                    color: #5e00bc;
                    z-index: 2;
                }

                .field-8 {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 250px;
                    height: 150px;
                    top: 620px;
                    left: 75.8%;
                    box-shadow: 10px 10px;
                    background-color: #0f0f0f;
                    color: #5e00bc;
                    z-index: 2;
                }
            </style>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flex would do you just right

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
  div {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body> 
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```